# iOS Simulator 6.0 эмуляция sms

Tags: xcode, ios, iphone

Можно ли каким-то образом протестировать на iOS Simulator функционал отправки sms  с помощью MessageUI описанный здесь: http://osxdev.ru/blog/ios/15.html

Или в симуляторе это неприменимо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После работы с документами на developer.apple.com выяснилось что тестировать такой функционал можно только на физическом устройстве, но не в симуляторе